# OnItemClickListener not recognised

Tags: java, android, listview, onclick

Bah, what am i doing wrong here I've set the onItemClickListener for the list view and the onClick
to take it to different activities but it's telling me it must use the method OnItemClicklistener and i have...

```
package org.iimed.www;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.iimed.www.R;
import org.iimed.www.CustomListViewAdapter;
import org.iimed.www.RowItem;

public class ImageTextListViewActivity extends Activity implements
        OnItemClickListener {

    public static final String[] titles = new String[] { "Penicillins",
            "Cephalosporins", "Monobactams", "Carbapenems","Macrolides","Tetracyclines",};

    public static final String[] descriptions = new String[] {
            "It is an aggregate accessory fruit",
            "It is the largest herbaceous flowering plant", "Citrus Fruit",
            "Mixed Fruits","none","none" };

    public static final Integer[] images = { R.drawable.antibiotic_buton,
            R.drawable.antibiotic_buton, R.drawable.antibiotic_buton, R.drawable.antibiotic_buton, R.drawable.antibiotic_buton,R.drawable.antibiotic_buton, };

    ListView listView;
    List<RowItem> rowItems;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.screj);

        rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
            RowItem item = new RowItem(images[i], titles[i], descriptions[i]);
            rowItems.add(item);


        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,
                R.layout.list_item, rowItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

               @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   {
             Intent intent = null ;
                switch (arg2) {
            case 0:
                intent  = new Intent(ImageTextListViewActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);          
                break;
            case 1:
            intent = new Intent(ImageTextListViewActivity.this, Miipet.class);
            startActivity(intent);
                break;
            default:
                break;



                }}}}
```

The adapter :

```
package org.iimed.www;


import java.util.List;
import org.iimed.www.R;
import org.iimed.www.RowItem;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {

   Context context;

   public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
           List<RowItem> items) {
       super(context, resourceId, items);
       this.context = context;
   }


   private class ViewHolder {
       ImageView imageView;
       TextView txtTitle;
       TextView txtDesc;
   }

   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       ViewHolder holder = null;
       RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

       LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
               .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       if (convertView == null) {
           convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
           holder = new ViewHolder();
           holder.txtDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
           holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
           holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
           convertView.setTag(holder);
       } else
           holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

       holder.txtDesc.setText(rowItem.getDesc());
       holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
       holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());

       return convertView;
   }
}
```

Comment: Please clear your question. What issue you are facing ? Do you get any error ?

Comment: Move one of your curly bracket to after : `listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);`

Comment: use 'public void onItemClick' is out of oncreate method

Comment: can you plz your paste your custom adapter which you are using to create this list.

Comment: Do you have button inside your listItem layout?

Comment: I tried that Aprian and it told me i needed to follow it with another } but when i put another }, it tells me i need to implement this public class ImageTextListViewActivity extends Activity implements
        OnItemClickListener {

Comment: No button in layout URAndroid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code and there are several problem

1) you cycling through elements and create the Adapter for each element

2)you implemented onItemClick inside onCreate

I paste a revision of your code but I have changed RowItem with Object and CustomListViewAdapter with ListAdapter so use you object there but this should be the structure of your code :)

```
package org.iimed.www;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
 import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class ImageTextListViewActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

public static final String[] titles = new String[] { "Penicillins",
    "Cephalosporins", "Monobactams",      "Carbapenems","Macrolides","Tetracyclines",};

public static final String[] descriptions = new String[] {
    "It is an aggregate accessory fruit",
    "It is the largest herbaceous flowering plant", "Citrus Fruit",
    "Mixed Fruits","none","none" };

public static final Integer[] images = { R.drawable.antibiotic_buton,
    R.drawable.antibiotic_buton, R.drawable.antibiotic_buton,   R.drawable.antibiotic_buton, R.drawable.antibiotic_buton,R.drawable.antibiotic_buton, };

ListView listView;
List<Object> rowItems;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screj);

    rowItems = new ArrayList<Object>();
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        Object item = new Object();
        rowItems.add(item);
    }

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(this,R.layout.list_item, rowItems);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = null ;
    switch (arg2) {
    case 0:
        intent  = new Intent(ImageTextListViewActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);          
        break;
    case 1:
        intent = new Intent(ImageTextListViewActivity.this, Miipet.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks, but i tried both of these and i get the same error as i posted in the above comment..I'm obviously closing off something where i shouldn't right?

Comment: Thank you very much it worked a charm, so i should have closed after RowItem item = new RowItem } then closed again after list view? so public void onItemClick shouldn't have been in onCreate. But i don't get what you mean by your first point" you cycling through elements and create the Adapter for each element"?

Comment: you didn't close the for brackets so everithing was repeated n times.

Answer (score 2):

Register for on click like this:

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ImageGridActivity.class);

              startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```